# asp.net: pass data between pages using delegate

Tags: webforms

I want to know if it is possible to pass data to another page without Querystrings or Session.

In other words: 
Can i do this using delegates or any other way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can POST data to another page (this is slightly different than using querystrings but may be too similar for your liking).  Any data POSTED to another web form can be read with Request.Form["name_of_control"].

In certain cases I've had to develop my own approach involving generating a GUID and passing that around from page-to-page.  Then any page can pull my data structures associated with a given GUID from a static key/value structure...  Similar to Sessions I suppose but I had more control over how it worked.  It allowed for any user to have multiple simultaneous windows/tabs open to my application and each one would work without affecting or being affected by the others (because each were passing around a different GUID).  Whatever approach you choose I do urge you to consider the fact that users may want to use your application via multiple windows/tabs at the same time.

The right tool for you depends on your needs.  Remember your challenge lies is making HTTP which is inherently stateless more state-ful.  This thread has a very good discussion on this topic:  [Best Practices for Passing Data Between Pages](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3207611/best-practices-for-passing-data-between-pages?rq=1)

Comment: Sample of which approach?  POSTing to another page?

Comment: Sorry... yes, your approach.
TKS!

Comment: Here is one example:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11149282/post-asp-net-form-data-to-another-page