# When I read the querystring? In the Event PageLoad? Best Practice

Tags: c#, asp.net

I need to work with querystring but i'm not sure when i shoud use. Permissions in my page depend of querystring.

I know, i can use in page_load but i need to be sure this is a best practice.

[EDIT]

If I use querystring to **permissons in my pag**e when i shoud use querystring?

Example:
Show some controls hide others.

[/EDIT]

Sorry my bad english!

Thanks!

Comment: In `page_load` event. 
`string v = Request.QueryString["param"];
 if (v != null)
 {
     ....
 }`

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3207611/best-practices-for-passing-data-between-pages

Comment: if my answer helped you make it as correct.

Answer (score 1):

If the query string name is ID

```
this.Request.Params["ID"]
```

will return the query string in the page as string value. **You can use it whatever you want**